# Selenium WebDriver issues with Material UI select fields (dropdown list)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, material-design

Hi I need to access to a Select Field component from the Material UI library. I'm using the traditional way but as expected is throwing an error because this library generates div elements instead of select.
Please any idea of how to select elements with this component?

WebSite Url: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

Error: "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "div".

The code I used is the follow:

```
public class MaterialUITest {

private WebDriver driver;
By selectFieldLocator = By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'undefined-undefined-Frequency')]/div[1]/div[2]");

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field");
}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
}
@Test
public void test() {
    WebElement selectField = driver.findElement(selectFieldLocator);
    Select dropdown = new Select(selectField);
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Weekly");
    WebElement option = dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption();
    System.out.println(option.getText());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand problem that you're having is not related to material itself it's more related to custom implementation of select, i.e. this is not select, you should treat this 'select' as regular web element and handle it respectively in other words you need to click on it to expand and then perform another click on required element to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element and copy full xpath.
Try with Full xpath it will work you need take the xpath of full tab because  inner elements are not enabled because of parent elements.